# How can I change the projection used by the QGIS Browser preview?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-browser

QGIS Browser has no settings in the UI. Is there any file or so where I can define this?

Comment: I didn't inspect the source code but the projection used to draw the data is most likely the projection of the data. Why reproject data in a preview?

Comment: the data does not carry projection info, so qgis uses just some projection. i would like to set this choice.